# Python - exact same loop works inconsistently 'int' object is not iterable - not iterating over int

Tags: python, for-loop

I need to run a loop twice in a function to do 2 different things. It works fine in one place but fails to run in the other, even though there is no discernible difference between the two.

This is the loop

```
for each in problem.getSuccessors(coord): #each in [((x,y), 'Dir', num)...]
```

It runs fine the second time, which is giving me an almost correct solution, but

```
def recursiveDFS(coord, stck, actions, visited, problem):
    repush = False
    print "ITERATE", problem.getSuccessors(coord)
    for each in problem.getSuccessors(coord): #each in [((x,y), 'Dir', num)...]
        if not each[0] in visited:
            repush = True

    if repush:
        stck.push(coord)

    if problem.isGoalState(coord):
        print coord, " is a goal state"
        return stck
    else:
        if coord in visited:
            print "revisited ", coord
        else:
            visited.append(coord)
            print "visited ", coord

        print "ITERATE", problem.getSuccessors(coord)    
        for each in problem.getSuccessors(coord): #each in [((x,y), 'Dir', num)...]
            if not each[0] in visited:
                print "PUSHED ", each
                stck.push(each)
                return recursiveDFS(each[0], stck, actions, visited, problem)

        new = stck.pop()
        print "popped ", new
        return recursiveDFS(new[0], stck, actions, visited, problem)
```

Here are some screenshots detailing the error. I can't imagine what's different between the first loop and the second.

[The second loop works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0USQe.png)

[When I uncomment the first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCNUG.png), it seems to think it is iterating over an int.

What's the difference?

Some additional info about the error on line 197 of searchAgents:
This is addressing the function getSuccessors, which should return what I am attempting to iterate over. It should be (and in the case of the second loop is)
a tuple containing: [(x, y), "Direction", int] where x and y are ints.

```
def getSuccessors(self, state):

    successors = []
    for action in [Directions.NORTH, Directions.SOUTH, Directions.EAST,    Directions.WEST]:
        x,y = state
        dx, dy = Actions.directionToVector(action)
        nextx, nexty = int(x + dx), int(y + dy)
        if not self.walls[nextx][nexty]:
            nextState = (nextx, nexty)
            cost = self.costFn(nextState)
            successors.append( ( nextState, action, cost) )

    # Bookkeeping for display purposes
    self._expanded += 1 # DO NOT CHANGE
    if state not in self._visited:
        self._visited[state] = True
        self._visitedlist.append(state)

    return successors
```

Comment: It's not exactly the same, the item can be added to visited between the loops and then your if will skip it.

Comment: Looks like that error occurs in a different function (line 197, with "x,y = state"). Have a look at that function, first.

Comment: @olofom yes, but that shouldn't have an effect. The 2nd version of the loop runs successfully several times, but the earlier version never does.

Comment: What is the code around line 197? What is the content of state and x and y?

Comment: for example >>> state = 34
>>> x,y = state

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    x,y = state
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @sabbahillel I added info about line 197 of the searchAgents file

Comment: If you put in a `print "State = ", state` what do you get?

Comment: @sabbahillel I added print "state = ", state to get successors, before the #Bookkeeping. It printed the x, y pair for coord everytime until the error. Before the error, it did not print.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED: looked back over the 
the issue is not in the for loop, it is the part right below the first for loop that pushes the `coord` into `stck`.

```
if repush:
    stck.push(coord)
```

this is only the coordinate instead of `each` which was likely what you intended to push, but this means that at the end of the function when you pop it back out calling it `new` it fails since it is only the coord.  I can't suggest a full solution since I'm not sure what the majority of your code is doing but that is why the output has "popped (3,5)" right before the error raised and why the first element of that is an integer instead of a coordinate.

Comment: This actually isn't true- coord is an (x, y) value, but coords are not pushed onto the stack. The items that the stack hold are in the format [(x, y), "Direction, int]. So stck.pop()[0] will give an (x, y) pair.

Comment: took another look at the output and changed the answer

Comment: This is exactly what I was overlooking. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error appears to be that state is set to an int value rather than a list. Check your actual code that handles state and initializes it.

```
>>> state = 34
>>> x,y = state

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    x,y = state
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

on the other hand

```
>>> state = [3, 4]
>>> x,y = state
>>> print x,y
3 4
```

Comment: You were on the right track. I greatly appreciate you taking the time to look at this and give feedback. Tadhg McDonald-Jensen was able to point out the error I was seeking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your loop, it is with the response returned by `problem.getSuccessors(coord)`. I suggest your store the outcome of this function in a variable once, and use that variable later. This will ensure that you're dealing with the same thing all the time. Unless I see how `problem.getSuccessors(coord)` handling `coord`, I cannot give you any additional suggestions.